# Shell.Application & errors

Tags: powershell

*To clarify, I am specifically asking about how to HANDLE errors when using Shell.Application. Or more to the point, CAN one handle errors, and IF SO, how. The font example is just that, an example of the current situation I am trying to solve. But the question remains, can one handle (not avoid, handle) an error when using Shell.Application? There may well be some subtlety to the answer, I.e in general you can, but specifically not in the fonts example. That seems to be the case, and I am inclined to decide that Shell.Application is old, broken technology that should simply not be used, because it can't be robust in all use cases, which to me says it's potentially fragile in any use case.*

I am attempting to refine my use of Shell.Application.CopyHere(), specifically for use installing fonts. What I hope to do is address the occasional error where a font file is corrupt or otherwise not a valid font file.
So far as I can tell from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-copyhere) there really is no way to address this. I can use argument value 16 *Respond with "Yes to All" for any dialog box that is displayed.* to perhaps get past the error, but with no return code I have no way to log a resulting error. Using `.CopyHere()` in PowerShell with a Try/Catch doesn't work either. Is this just old technology from a time when Microsoft just accepted things failing ungracefully? Or am I missing a technique that solves the issue?

EDIT: Based on that link I provided, I tried the 1024 argument, *Do not display a user interface if an error occurs.* Like so

```
$fontFolder.CopyHere($fontFilePath, 1024)
```

Doesn't seem to do what it says it does, since I am seeing a dialog that says

```
Cannot install bogus.ttf
The file ... does not appear to be a valid font.
```

So, not only not able to get a meaningful error back, but the presence of an error disrupts execution of the script and requires user interaction. Ugh.

EDIT 2:
Not really a minimal code example, since my question is CAN this be done, even before how. But this is what I just tried.

```
fontFilePath = '\\px\Rollouts\Misc\Fonts\bogus.ttf'
$fontFolderPath = "$env:windir\Fonts"
$fontFolder = $(New-Object -ComObject:Shell.Application).Namespace($fontFolderPath)
$fontFolder.CopyHere($fontFilePath, 1024)
```

Based on what that 1024 argument claims to do, I would expect this to fail, but also not stop processing while a dialog waits for user interaction.

Also, worth noting that bogus.ttf is simply an empty text file renamed with TTF extension. So, guaranteed not to successfully install a font.

Comment: "What I hope to do is address the occasional error where a font file is corrupt or otherwise not a valid font file" - well, what do you want to do? Retry the copy operation? Skip it? Break?

Comment: Your question needs improvement, not only to cater for the questions raised in the above comment, but to provide a [mcve] of the code you're running, and show the issue you're trying to address, together with the debugging information necessary for us to replicate your issue. We cannot help you to fix a problem without being able to accurately produce it ourselves.

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen I would want to know the error happened so I could log that an error happened, and skip some followup tasks that only happen if the font installed properly. If I could log a detailed error like I can get with try/catch that's even better, as it helps with troubleshooting. But just being able to identify an error would be a good start. And being able to continue without the user needing to OK the error dialog that gets thrown.

Comment: @Gordon please provide what you have already tried to handle this case, otherwise the question is considered off-topic for StackOverflow. This is what is meant by providing a [mcve].

Comment: @bender-the-greatest I added the code I am currently trying, but the MRE example raises a question for me. It is considered inappropriate to ask a question like "Can X even be done?" I would expect Code Review to, well, require code, but I would have thought that Stack Overflow was open to higher level questions like "What are the pros and cons of dependency injection" where there is no code, there isn't even a language specified, but there is room for (to me at least) useful discussion at a higher level. Current post isn't an example of that, but it's a question that came to mind.

Comment: StackOverflow is more meant for debugging issues within existing code, theoretical questions used to be allowed but an Exchange was created a while back for these sorts of questions (used to be called Programmers but now looks to be [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)), so "how to X" type questions are more appropriate there these days.

Comment: @bender-the-greatest Gotcha. I have to admit the group names don't make it easy to comply with the rules. I'll make sure to put my more conceptual questions in Software Engineering. And now I think this post is in compliance.

Comment: I removed my comment as I figured out how to do it programmatically, will post as an answer when I get a few minutes.

Comment: For what it's worth, the original title IS CORRECT. I really would like to learn how to HANDLE errors, not AVOID errors. Avoiding errors is good, but can't be fully depended on. I think any robust solution needs to also handle unexpected errors, and it SEEMS like Microsoft just hasn't provided a means to do that.

Comment: You want to handle errors without a modal dialog box blocking further execution. The answer I provided also gives how to install fonts to workaround the limitations of the COM object. I re-titled the question to appropriately reflect your ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the Fonts folder, while it does implement `Folder.CopyHere`, does not evaluate the flags passed in the second parameter. Doesn't seem there are any other standard utilities to install fonts programmatically, or verify the integrity of the TTF non-interactively.

So this leaves us the option of rolling our own Font registration using the Win32 API. Basically, you have to copy the font to the Fonts folder:

```
# For .NET versions earlier than 4.0, hardcode to C:\Windows\Fonts
# Fonts special folder is new in 4.0
$fontDir = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath([System.Environment.SpecialFolder]::Fonts)
Copy-Item C:\Path\To\Font.ttf "${fontDir}\Font.ttf"
```

This next call isn't strictly necessary, as it only adds the font temporarily to your user session, but it does function as an integrity check to see if the font is valid and can be imported. You need to P/Invoke `AddFontResource` from the Win32 API:

```
Add-Type -Name Gdi32 -Namespace Win32 -MemberDefinition @"
  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
  public static extern int AddFontResource(string lpszFilename);
"@

# Returns 1 on success or 0 on failure, if you want your error checking here
[Win32.Gdi32]::AddFontResource("${fontDir}\FontFileName.ttf")
```

And then register it at the following registry key. This piece is necessary for persisting the font you copied to `$fontDir`:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts' -Name "FontName" -Value "FontFileName.ttf"
```

You can programmatically get the `FontName` using the [`PrivateFontCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection?view=netframework-4.8) class, and the `Families[x].Name` property under that, where `x` is the index of the font in the collection you want the name for.

---

To address your edit, there isn't going to be a "one size fits all" approach when it comes to handling errors in `Shell.Application`. There are multiple reasons to avoid using `Shell.Application`, such as:

- APIs are wrought with legacy behavior, such as using modal dialogs to report errors
- Windows standards are implemented inconsistently, such as Fonts ignoring the documented CopyFile flags
- Not available in a non-interactive session

The first two points are cases the example in your question hits. The third comes into play in many automation scenarios, especially when a non-interactive service accounts are used to execute commands. There are very few cases where something can *only* be done via `Shell.Application`, and as such it's almost always best to avoid it if there is an alternative API. Your font installation scenario is an excellent example of this.

Comment: Hmmm. I had been down a path like this, using `$fontFamilies = $fontCollection.Families | Foreach-Object {$_.Name}` to build my font family list. But that's always in alphabetical order, which isn't always what you get with a manual install. Time to see if I can sort by index and get a better match. 
I don't know that it matters, but I prefer to have my automation result in exactly the same result as a manual process if at all possible.

Comment: Sitka.ttc being an example of one that is preinstalled with a name that doesn't match what my code above would produce.

Comment: I don't understand the issue. You're concerned the fonts might get installed out of alphabetical order of the font family name?

Comment: I am concerned with 1: having my automation produce EXACTLY the same result as a manual process, and 2: handling errors when using Shell.Application. In first case, when installing sitka.ttc, a manual install produces a property name of `Sitka Small & Sitka Text & Sitka Subheading & Sitka Heading & Sitka Display & Sitka Banner (TrueType)`, but all I get from `PrivateFontCollection` is `Sitka Banner & Sitka Display & Sitka Heading & Sitka Small & Sitka Subheading & Sitka Text (TrueType)`. The order is different. On the second point, fonts is just an example, I am looking for a general answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address your question edit, but basically avoid `Shell.Application` for most scenarios if an alternative API is available

Comment: I'm also not sure if the property name being out of order here matters, I don't often do font installations via PowerShell.

Comment: I'm not sure either about the order. I can't find anything definitive one way or the other. In testing I haven't seen it matter, but it's Windows and who knows what could crop up later. That, and the bit about non interactive sessions seals the deal, since that is something I want to add later.

Comment: I am curious... I have had some success just doing a simple copy of the font file to the appropriate folder (`Copy-Item` in Powershell) then registering as you show. What else is  `AddFontResource` doing beyond the copy?

Comment: So `AddFontResource` is a bit redundant with recent Windows' builds, as new fonts are added when the folder is simply copied to, but this wasn't always the case. I'm not sure when this behavior was changed to be honest. `AddFontResource` actually only adds the Font to the current user session (it's a temporary font), while the registry key is what makes it load again with each new logon session. But if you want to spot any fonts with errors before you copy it, `AddFontResource` will return 0 on failure.

Comment: For your case you may be able to eschew the registry registration of the font, and just call `AddFontResource`. If it returns `1`, then just `Copy-Item` the font into the Fonts directory. You may want to test this behavior on all versions of Windows before determining you don't need the manual registration, however.

Comment: Ah, that tidbit about `AddFontResource` as a test of font file validity is great. I am pretty sure after that I need both the copy and the registration. Especially since I have to support everything from Windows 7 through current Windows 10 builds. Architecture is a funny business, with some really lame upgrade schedules. :) In any case, some new code to write tomorrow, and lots of testing to do.

Comment: Also, I didn't think about this because of the PowerShell nature of the question, but why not deploy your fonts with Group Policy? Fonts would be pre-vetted (assumedly) and deployed whenever the client checks in. Deployment in this case will work across all supported versions of Windows, it boils down to a File setting to place the font in `C:\Windows\Fonts` and the associated Registry setting to register the font with the OS.

Comment: My market is architecture firms, where Group Policy expertise is hard to come by, and there are a TON of other install/customization tasks that need to be done that can't be done with GPO, often because it has to be done in user context. Powershell and XML based data files allows me to handle everything in one place.